# How to avoid NaN in numpy implementation of logistic regression?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, nan, logistic-regression

**EDIT:** I already made significant progress. My current question is written after my last edit below and can be answered without the context.

I currently follow Andrew Ng's [Machine Learning Course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/week/3) on Coursera and tried to implement [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) today.

**Notation:**

- `X` is a `(m x n)`-matrix with vectors of input variables as rows (`m` training samples of `n-1` variables, the entries of the first column are equal to 1 everywhere to represent a constant).
- `y` is the corresponding vector of expected output samples (column vector with `m` entries equal to `0` or `1`)
- `theta` is the vector of model coefficients (row vector with `n` entries)

For an input row vector `x` the model will predict the probability `sigmoid(x * theta.T)` for a positive outcome.

This is my Python3/numpy implementation:

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

vec_sigmoid = np.vectorize(sigmoid)

def logistic_cost(X, y, theta):
    summands = np.multiply(y, np.log(vec_sigmoid(X*theta.T))) + np.multiply(1 - y, np.log(1 - vec_sigmoid(X*theta.T)))
    return - np.sum(summands) / len(y)


def gradient_descent(X, y, learning_rate, num_iterations):
    num_parameters = X.shape[1]                                 # dim theta
    theta = np.matrix([0.0 for i in range(num_parameters)])     # init theta
    cost = [0.0 for i in range(num_iterations)]

    for it in range(num_iterations):
        error = np.repeat(vec_sigmoid(X * theta.T) - y, num_parameters, axis=1)
        error_derivative = np.sum(np.multiply(error, X), axis=0)
        theta = theta - (learning_rate / len(y)) * error_derivative
        cost[it] = logistic_cost(X, y, theta)

    return theta, cost
```

This implementation seems to work fine, but I encountered a problem when calculating the logistic-cost. At some point the gradient descent algorithm converges to a pretty good fitting `theta` and the following happens:

For some input row `X_i` with expected outcome `1` `X * theta.T` will become positive with a good margin (for example `23.207`). This will lead to `sigmoid(X_i * theta)` to become *exactly* `1.0000` (this is because of lost precision I think). This is a good prediction (since the expected outcome is equal to `1`), but this breaks the calculation of the logistic cost, since `np.log(1 - vec_sigmoid(X*theta.T))` will evaluate to `NaN`. This shouldn't be a problem, since the term is multiplied with `1 - y = 0`, but once a value of `NaN` occurs, the whole calculation is broken (`0 * NaN = NaN`).

How should I handle this in the vectorized implementation, since `np.multiply(1 - y, np.log(1 - vec_sigmoid(X*theta.T)))` is calculated in every row of `X` (not only where `y = 0`)?

**Example input:**

```
X = np.matrix([[1. , 0. , 0. ],
               [1. , 1. , 0. ],
               [1. , 0. , 1. ],
               [1. , 0.5, 0.3],
               [1. , 1. , 0.2]])

y = np.matrix([[0],
               [1],
               [1],
               [0],
               [1]])
```

Then `theta, _ = gradient_descent(X, y, 10000, 10000)` (yes, in this case we can set the learning rate *this* large) will set `theta` as:

```
theta = np.matrix([[-3000.04008972,  3499.97995514,  4099.98797308]])
```

This will lead to `vec_sigmoid(X * theta.T)` to be the really good prediction of:

```
np.matrix([[0.00000000e+00],      # 0
           [1.00000000e+00],      # 1
           [1.00000000e+00],      # 1
           [1.95334953e-09],      # nearly zero
           [1.00000000e+00]])     # 1
```

but `logistic_cost(X, y, theta)` evaluates to `NaN`.

**EDIT:**

I came up with the following solution. I just replaced the `logistic_cost` function with:

```
def new_logistic_cost(X, y, theta):
    term1 = vec_sigmoid(X*theta.T)
    term1[y == 0] = 1
    term2 = 1 - vec_sigmoid(X*theta.T)
    term2[y == 1] = 1
    summands = np.multiply(y, np.log(term1)) + np.multiply(1 - y, np.log(term2))
    return - np.sum(summands) / len(y)
```

By using the mask I just calculate `log(1)` at the places at which the result will be multiplied with zero anyway. Now `log(0)` will only happen in wrong implementations of gradient descent.

Open questions: How can I make this solution more clean? Is it possible to achieve a similar effect in a cleaner way?

Comment: FYI: If you don't mind the dependency on scipy, you can replace `vec_sigmoid` with [`scipy.special.expit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I don't mind in general and just wanted to understand the algorithm better by implementing it once myself. This would not solve my problem though, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, but it will likely be faster, and more accurate in the tails of the function.  I think you could fix your problem by using [`scipy.special.xlog1py`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.xlog1py.html).  That is, replace `np.multiply(1 - y, np.log(1 - vec_sigmoid(X*theta.T)))` with `xlog1py(1 - y, -expit(X*theta.T)))`.  I made this suggestion an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using SciPy, you could import [`expit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html) and [`xlog1py`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.xlog1py.html) from `scipy.special`:

```
from scipy.special import expit, xlog1py
```

and replace the expression

```
np.multiply(1 - y, np.log(1 - vec_sigmoid(X*theta.T)))
```

with

```
xlog1py(1 - y, -expit(X*theta.T))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but I ran into the same problem, and maybe it can help others in the future, I actually solved it by implementing normalization on the data before appending X0.

```
def normalize_data(X):
    mean = np.mean(X, axis=0)
    std = np.std(X, axis=0)
    return (X-mean) / std
```

After this all worked well!